# Invalid MEX-file - Compiled with VisualStudio 2013

Tags: c++, matlab, visual-studio, mex

I have a .mexw32-file which is compiled in VisualStudio 2013 and i try to call that function in Matlab 2013. The mex-file use a libary ("plug_feedfwd.lib") to control a mirror.
I can compile the project in VS2013 without failures and warnigns, so it seems that all libarys and header-files are included correctly. 
But if i try to call the mex-file in Matlab, it trows the following exception:

```
"Invalid MEX-file -pathOfTheMexFile-: The specified module could not be found."
```

If I comment all lines where methodes call the libary, the mex-file works in matlab. So it seems that Matlab got a problem with this library, but VisualStudio can deal with it.

I have found this link but it didnt help much:

http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/invalid-mex-file-error.html

1. The matlab-version must be compatible cause i can call the mex-function if i dont use methodes from the library.
2. The dependencywalker show always missing librarys, also if the mex-function works - and if i use my invalid mexfile the missing librarys are the same as before
3. I also tryied to copy all librarys in the same folder as the mex-file

My System:
Windows 8.1 x64,
Matlab 2013 x32,
Visual Studio: 2013,
Mex-function: x32,

has anyone a idear what can i try next?
gereetings, Stefan

Comment: It is most likely because MATLAB is not finding a dependent library when loading the mex file. Try adding paths to dependency walker and make sure dependency walker finds all of your libraries. Then try putting all of them in the same folder as mex file.

Comment: Be sure to use the 32-bit plug_feedfwd.lib, and have the associated 32-bit DLL in the folder of the MEX file.

Comment: thanks for the help!
Indeed the problem where two missing .dll's in the folder of the mex-folder.
I found it with the dependencywalker.
Thanks:)